# Cannot display my calendar well in Internet Explorer, CSS trouble

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, calendar

I have a calendar that I created in PHP 
the problem is, it is not displayed well in Internet Explorer
In Chrome all is well

I use DIV instead of Table

The complete code here and you can see a demo here

http://www.guadadvent.org/calendrier_essaie.php

```
   .today{
          font-weight:bold;
          color:red;
      }

      .mois {
      background:#FFF;
      height:30px;
      line-height:30px;
      width:100%;
      text-align:center;
      margin-right:-100px;"
      }

      .jours {
    background:#FFF; 
    border:1px #999933 solid;
    padding:5px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:-3px;
    margin-bottom:1px;"
      }
      .cellule {
           background:#FFF;
           border:1px #999933 solid;
           padding:5px;
           height:70px;
           width:100px;
           float:left;
           text-align:right;
           margin-right:-3px;
           margin-bottom:1px;
      }

      .cellule_vide {
    padding:5px;
    height:70px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:-1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;"
      }

      .cellule:hover {
                background:#CCC;
                border:1px solid red;
      }
      .separateur {
         style="clear:both;" 
      }

      .cadre {
          display:inline-block;
          background:#CCC;
          position:relative;
      }
      .nav_gauche {
          position:absolute;
          top:0px;
          left:0px;
          text-decoration:none;
          padding-left:50px;

      }

      .nav_droite {
           position:absolute;
           top:0px;
           right:0px;
           text-decoration:none;
           padding-right:50px;
      }

      </style>



<?php
$tabmois = array ("","Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet","Août","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Décembre");
$tabjours = array ("","Dimanche","Lundi","Mardi","Mercredi","Jeudi","Vendredi","Samedi");?>

<?php $an=$_REQUEST["a"];
if(empty($an)) $an=date("Y");
$mois=$_REQUEST["m"];
$jour_serveur=date("j");
$mois_serveur=date("m");
if(empty($mois)) $mois=$mois_serveur;
if($mois==12) $mois_suivant=1; else $mois_suivant=$mois+1;
if($mois==1) $mois_precedent=12; else $mois_precedent=$mois-1;?>


<?php    
$premJourdumois = date("w" , mktime(0,0,0,$mois,1,$an) )+1;// en chiffre, +1 si calendrier comence par dimanche, soit 1 pour dimanche
$nbJoursdanslemois = date("t" , mktime(0,0,0,$mois,1,$an)); // respecte les années bixectiles
$nbdecellulesvidesavantdebut = $premJourdumois-1; // nom de variable explicite
?>


<div class="cadre">

<div class="mois">
  <div class="nav_gauche" > <a href="?m=<?php echo $mois_precedent;?>">&lt;&lt;</a> </div>
  <?php echo $tabmois[$mois];?>
  <div class="nav_droite"> <a href="?m=<?php echo $mois_suivant;?>">&gt;&gt;</a> </div>
  </div>

        <div class="separateur"></div>

<?php // les jours
for ($i=1;$i<=7;$i++) {?>
<div class="jours"><?php echo $tabjours[$i];?> </div>
<?php } ?>

<div class="separateur"></div>

<?php // cellules vide avant le debut de l'affichage
 for ($i=1;$i<=$nbdecellulesvidesavantdebut;$i++) {?>
  <div class="cellule_vide"></div>
    <?php }?>

<?php // affichage du calendrier
for ($i=1;$i<=$nbJoursdanslemois;$i++) {?>
<?php if(($i==$jour_serveur) and ($mois==$mois_serveur)) $auj="today"; else $auj=""; // si c'est le jour d'aujourd'ui on met une classe spéciale?>
  <div class="<?php echo $auj;?> cellule"><?php echo $i;?></div>

   <?php // saut si on liste une semaine soit 7 jours
   if(($i+$nbdecellulesvidesavantdebut)%7 == 0 ) {?>
        <div class="separateur"></div>

    <?php }?>

    <?php }?>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried with internet explorer 8

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404547/ie8-float-issue-with-css